# Replace string one by one at run-time in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, replace

I have managed to replace all the strings in the datagridview at run-time.Now i want to replace the string one by one on the click of the button.This is the code for the replacement of all the strings on a single button click.

```
private void button9_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var original = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
        var clone = original.Clone();
        var ordinal = original.Columns["Stringtext"].Ordinal;
        var tra = original.Columns[6].Ordinal;
        var che = original.Columns[10].Ordinal;
        for (int i = 0; i < original.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var values = original.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(values[tra].ToString()) && Convert.ToBoolean(values[che].ToString()))
            {
                values[ordinal] = ((values[ordinal].ToString()).ToLower())
                    .Replace(textBox6.Text.ToLower(), textBox7.Text);
                clone.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            else
            {
                values[ordinal] = values[ordinal];
                clone.Rows.Add(values);
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = clone;
        string filterBy;
        filterBy = "Stringtext Like '%" + textBox7.Text + "%'";
        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = filterBy;
}
```

I want to replace a single string in a row on the click of a button then on the next button click the next string in the row is replaced.etc.any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easy way to do what you want is to keep a counter on how many times did the user pressed the button. that way you can tell this is the 1st, 2end or 3rd time the user clicked the button and by so replace the needed cell
      private int counter = 0;

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // change the cell = counter
     counter++;
  }
```